# Get INSERT INTO statement from SQL statements string in Python

Tags: python, sql, regex

I have a string like the following:

```
sql = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

ALTER TABLE table1 DROP PRIMARY KEY;

INSERT INTO table1 (id, created, name, telefonnummer, erPatient_id) VALUES
    (1, '2015-08-06 12;09:08', ' ', ' ', 16528),
    (2, '2015-08-06 12:43:11', ' ', ' ', 16529)
;

INSERT INTO table2 (comment, id) VALUES
('hello this is a semicolon ;', 2);"""
```

And I would like to get the statement INSERT INTO table1:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, created, name, telefonnummer, erPatient_id) VALUES
        (1, '2015-08-06 12;09:08', ' ', ' ', 16528),
        (2, '2015-08-06 12:43:11', ' ', ' ', 16529)
    ;
```

I can't split the string with `sql.split(';)` because there are semicolons within the VALUES to insert.

I have tried with regex with no success:

```
import re
pattern_string = r"INSERT INTO table1[(]*[^)]+\)[^)]"
q = re.findall(pattern_string, data, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

In the real string there will be thousands of values to insert and dozens of tables.

Comment: If your data is not regular then a regular expression is the wrong tool. You need a parsing engine. This problem is nothing new; the same issue exists for CSV and countless other things.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
import re
pattern_string = r"\bINSERT INTO \w+\s.*?;\s*$"
q = re.findall(pattern_string, data, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/VqHmug/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INSERT INTO              'INSERT INTO '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters 1 or more times 
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        end of a line
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library [SQLGlot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot).

```
import sqlglot
import sqlglot.expressions as exp

sql = ...

for expression in sqlglot.parse(sql):
    if isinstance(expression, exp.Insert):
        print(expression)
```